# How do I pass the UnityContainer as a parameter to a registration in a Unity IOC xml configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I have an implementation of a factory interface that uses an IOC container to create it's objects.

The container is a automatic property on the Factory, and ideally I would like to inject this property with same container where the factory is being registered.

For clarity I have described what I would like it to look like below.

```
<container name="MyContainer">
    <register type="IControllerFactory" mapTo="UnityControllerFactory">        
        <property name="UnityContainer" value="MyContainer" />
    </register>
</container>
```

Of course I have registered a class after this that automatically injects this registration into it's IControllerFactory property.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IUnityContainer registered with itself by default.  You can just set up your constructor like this:

```
public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer unityContainer) 
{
   this.unityContainer = unityContainer;
}
```

No addition configuration is needed.... the dependency will be resolved hassle-free.